# Create two subclasses for chequing and saving account in java

Tags: java

I need to create a "chequingAccount" and "savingAccount" subclasses for my "Account" class. Moreover, every subclass has their own "account number". For example, chequing account should start with "CA-###" and saving account should start with "SA-###" (###- any numbers). I do not know how to make "Account" class to recognize which account which just knowing the first two letters of the account number. Here is my how I did it(probably wrong one) in Account class code:

```
public class Account {

    private String accountNumber;
    private double balance;
    private boolean active;
    private ArrayList<String> transactionInfo;

    /**
     * Default constructor to create Account objects
     */
    public Account() {
        super();

    }

    /**
     * Overloaded Account constructor
     * 
     * @param accountNumber
     *            to set the accountNumber field
     * @param balance
     *            to set the balance field
     * @param transactionInfo to add transaction information about every deposit and withdrawl
     */
    public Account(String accountNumber, double balance) {
        super();
        if (accountNumber != null) {
            this.accountNumber = accountNumber;
        }
        setBalance(balance);
        active = true;
        transactionInfo = new ArrayList<String>();
    }

    /**
     * accessor for the accountNumber field
     * 
     * @return the accountNumber as a String
     */
    public String getAccountNumber() {
        return accountNumber;
    }

    /**
     * Method to change account types
     * @param accountNumber the accountNumber to set
     */
    public void setAccountNumber(String accountNumber) {
        if(getAccountNumber().substring(0,1).equals("SA")) {
            this.accountNumber = ;
        } else if(getAccountNumber().substring(0,1).equals("CH")) {
            this.accountNumber = "Chequing account";
        } else if(getAccountNumber().substring(0,1).equals("GL")){
            this.accountNumber = "Gold account";
        } else {
            System.out.println("ERROR");
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my "ChequingAccount" code:

```
public class ChequingAccount extends Account {
    /**
     * Variables
     */
    private final double FEE = 1.0;
    int numberOfCheques;

    /**
     * Default constructor
     */
    public ChequingAccount() {
        super();
    }

    /**
     * Overloaded constructor
     *
     * @param accountNumber String to initialize the accountNumber field
     * @param balance String to initialize the balance field
     * @param numberOfCheques to initialize the numberOfCheques fields
     */
    public ChequingAccount(String accountNumber, double balance, int numberOfCheques) {
        super(accountNumber, balance);
        setNumberOfCheques(3);
    }

    /**
     * Override setBalance method
     *
     * @param balance the balance to set
     */
    public void setBalance(double balance) {
        if (balance > 0) {
            super.setBalance(balance);
        } else {
            System.out.println("Number should be more than 0");
        }
    }

    /**
     * @return the numberOfCheques as an int
     */
    public int getNumberOfCheques() {
        return numberOfCheques;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param numberOfCheques to set numberOfCheques field
     */
    public void setNumberOfCheques(int numberOfCheques) {
        if (numberOfCheques >= 0) {
            this.numberOfCheques = numberOfCheques;
        } else {
            System.out.println("Number should be more than 0");
        }
    }

    /**
     * Override substractFromBalance method
     * @param amount the amount to substract from account
     */
    public void subtractFromBalance(double amount) {
        if (amount > 0) {
            if (getNumberOfCheques() <= 2) {
                super.subtractFromBalance(amount);
                setNumberOfCheques(getNumberOfCheques() + 1);
            } else {
                System.out.println("You have used your monthly limit");
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("ERROR. Invalid number");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "ChequingAccount [numberOfCheques=" + numberOfCheques + ", getAccountNumber()=" + getAccountNumber() +
            ", toString()=" + super.toString() + "]";
    }



}
```

I am new to Java and I hope that you can help me fix this issue.
Thank you!

Comment: Account isn't supposed to know that. I don't really understand the issue you are having. Account isn't even supposed to know there are subclasses.

Comment: This check will always be false: `getAccountNumber().substring(0,1).equals("SA")` because `substring(0,1)` will return a String of length 1. You probably want to use `substring(0, 2)` to get the first two characters in a String.